# Failure to install Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

Tying to install a Laravel 9 project.

Updated Composer from 2.0.8 to 2.3.10

Running `composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "9.*"`

Gives me :   `Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 9.* in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extens ions and Composer version.`

Comment: what is your php version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your PHP version, because laravel 9 required php >= 8.0
[Server Requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#server-requirements)

Answer (score 1):

PHP issue, update PHP at least to 8.0
OR
Use Laravel 8 ,that supports php 7.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your php version 8.0 or more.

laravel 9 requard at least 8.0 php version.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade you php version to < 8 and i recomde to upgrade your node js if you are using laragon node js is in 14.16.1 so upgrade it to it not an obligation but its better